# Best practice: Python development environment with docker for mac

Tags: python, macos, docker, virtualenv, docker-for-mac

I work on my mac and have a python-flask application running inside a container. I am using Docker for mac.

**Purpose:** I want my app to reload automatically everytime I make a change in code. I want to access and make changes to the code from my IDE(atom) in mac.

My Dockerfile creates a virtualenv(/app/venv) when I build the image.

```
WORKDIR /app
ADD ./myapp /app
RUN virtualenv venv
RUN venv/bin/activate && pip install requirements.lock
```

When I run the container, I mount the code volume so that I can access and make changes to code from local IDE.

```
volumes:
  - ./myapp:/app
```

**Problem**: The problem with this approach is my venv folder which got created in image build disappears because of the volume mount i made.

What is the best practice around it?

Comment: Why make this more complicated than it needs to be? Use virtualenv **or** mount the app volume. You do not need virtualenv in a container

Comment: To make cricket_007's answer more clear, remove the line RUN virtualenv venv and your problem will just go away.

Comment: Thanks it worked !